# Remote push notifications call didReceiveRemoteNotification even if user terminated the app (by waking up with region monitoring service)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I have a tricky question. I know that the apple docs specify that if the user manually terminates the app it is not waken up by the system when it receives an notification. All my notifications have **content-available** set to 1 so the **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:** should be fired in case of a new notification arrived.

I've looked at an app that manages to wake by an notification even if it was manually terminated. I am guessing that it uses regional monitoring to wake (i am 90% sure on that because its main feature is region monitoring), so i know it is possible.

Test case: I've terminated the app (on terminate i added a region and started region monitoring services) -> When i exit the region i see that the system wakes the app (so from suspended it enters background state) -> if i send a remote notification the **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:** is NOT fired.

I looked at a lot of documention, examples, tutorials and articles on the background remote notifications but none say anything about this exact case. Here is one that specifies simple playout scenarios: http://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/ 
I cannot see anything in the docs that specify this exact case.

Currently, if you press the home button the app receives remote notifications and the **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:** method is fired. (i have **remote-notification** set in **UIBackgroundModes**)

Has anyone encountered this problem?

EDIT:

So i just noticed that if i terminate the app, wake it with regional monitoring and receive notifications while attached to Xcode for debugging they WORK ! If i am not attached to the debugger they DON'T WORK. This is very strange.

Comment: Where are you monitoring for the notification? If the app is terminated and wakes up from a notification event, the notification is being passed in the launchoptions dictionary of the UIApplicationDelegate `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: Yes, i am monitoring the **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**, i hava a breakpoint and logs, it enters just when the app is waken by the regional monitoring, but not after when the notification is received.